# Using react-query inside next-mdx-remote MDX Components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-query, mdxjs

I'm using `next-mdx-remote` in my next.js application. One of the components I'm passing to it does a API call via axios. This works fine. I now want to move to `react-query` however. I get the following error:

> No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one

I think I understand this error, but the thing is that I do have a `QueryClient` set in my  `QueryClientProvider` in my `_app.js` file. Fetching via react-query also works in other pages & components, that are not part of my MDX structure.

I'm wondering what to do now? Do I need to configure something in `next-mdx-remote` for it to realise where my QueryClient is? For example here:

```
const mdxSource = await renderToString(content, { components });
```

The Component that fetches via react-query is part of this `components` object here that I pass down. However, everything in nextjs is by default rendered via `_app.js` - so I don't understand why it wouldn't find it?

`_app.js` :

```
  <QueryClientProvider client={queryClientRef.current}>
                <Hydrate state={pageProps.dehydratedState}>
                    <SettingsContextWrapper>
                        <Layout>
                            <GlobalStyles />
                            <Component {...pageProps} />
                        </Layout>
                    </SettingsContextWrapper>
                </Hydrate>
            </QueryClientProvider>
```

(and this all works in non-mdx contexts)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, `renderToString` creates a new root, so if you render a component with it that relies on react context (like `useQuery` does), you must specify the Provider with it:

```
const mdxSource = await renderToString(<QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>{ components }</QueryClientProvider>);
```